# Dead store to List object - how to solve?

Tags: java, sonarqube

On this below line#5 ,Sonar Code analysis showing issue  "Dead store to eventList in"  , How to solve this through my code?

**Sonar code analysis says :**  This instruction assigns a value to a local variable, but the value is not read or used in any subsequent instruction. Often, this indicates an error, because the value computed is never used.
    Note that Sun's javac compiler often generates dead stores for final local variables. Because SpotBugs is a bytecode-based tool, there is no easy way to eliminate these false positives.

---

```
@GetMapping(path = Constants.GET_REPORT, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<Map> getReport(@PathVariable(required = false) String keyword) {
        HashMap<Object, Object> sitesMap = new LinkedHashMap<>(); 
        try {
            List<EventV1> myList = new ArrayList<EventV1>();  // <<------------problem here  (Dead store to myList in..)
            if (keyword != null && !keyword.equalsIgnoreCase("null")) {// search of the keyword
                myList = eventService.getBySearch(keyword);
            } else {
                myList = eventService.getSomething();
            }
            if (myList != null && myList.size() > 0) {
                LOGGER.info("-size of the all events" + myList.size());
                sitesMap.put(Constants.SUCCESS, true);
                sitesMap.put(Constants.SIZE, myList.size());
                sitesMap.put("mylist", myList); 
                return new ResponseEntity<Map>(sitesMap, HttpStatus.OK);
            } else {
                sitesMap.put(Constants.SUCCESS, false);
                sitesMap.put("size", 0);
                sitesMap.put("mylist", null); 
                return new ResponseEntity<Map>(sitesMap, HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
            }
        } catch (Exception exc) { 
            throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.EXPECTATION_FAILED, REGISTER_FAIL_MSG, exc);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you created unnecessary `ArrayList` object. Just replace:

```
List<EventV1> myList = new ArrayList<EventV1>();
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
if (keyword != null && !keyword.equalsIgnoreCase("null")) {
    myList = eventService.getBySearch(keyword);
} else {
    myList = eventService.getSomething();
}
```

with

```
List<EventV1> myList;

if (keyword != null && !keyword.equalsIgnoreCase("null")) {
    myList = eventService.getBySearch(keyword);
} else {
    myList = eventService.getSomething();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can assign `myList` to null during declaration. Assigning it to `new ArrayList<EventV1>()` is useless as it is anyway taking the result from a method call : `eventService.getBySearch(keyword)` or `eventService.getSomething()`. You basically assigned some memory for `new ArrayList<EventV1>()` but immediately dereferenced it, thus wasting some valuable memory.